# Multiple linear regression: standard deviations of predicted values

Tags: r, multiple-regression

I'm struggling to understand the results of simple multiple linear regressions -- specifically, the standard deviations of predictions.

Say that I have a data set where a variable **density** was measured every season between 2000 and 2005.

```
# Create dummy data set 
df.tst <- data.frame(density = runif(24, 0, 1),
                     year = as.factor(rep(2000:2005, 4)),
                     season = c(rep("Fall", 6), rep("Spring", 6), rep("Summer", 6), rep("Winter",6)))
```

Now, I fit a model to this data using the **lm** function.

```
# Fit linear model to data
fitted.model <- lm(density ~ year + season, data=df.tst)
```

Then, I add the model predictions to my data frame, so that I can examine them.

```
# Add model predictions to data frame
df.tst <- data.frame(df.tst, prediction = predict(fitted.model))
```

Next, I look at the mean and standard deviations of predicted **density** for each season.

```
# Compare seasons
df.tst %>% 
  filter(season == "Spring") %>% 
  mutate(mean = mean(prediction), sd = sd(prediction))

df.tst %>% 
  filter(season == "Summer") %>% 
  mutate(mean = mean(prediction), sd = sd(prediction))

df.tst %>% 
  filter(season == "Winter") %>% 
  mutate(mean = mean(prediction), sd = sd(prediction))

df.tst %>% 
  filter(season == "Fall") %>% 
  mutate(mean = mean(prediction), sd = sd(prediction))
```

For all seasons, the mean value is different. Makes sense. However, the standard deviation for each season is ***exactly*** the same. I expect that this is somehow related to the least-square fitting process, but I don't understand why this should be the case. Similarly, if I compared years instead of seasons, the means would all be different, but the standard deviations would be the same. Can someone enlighten me as to why this is the case, please?

Comment: They are the same because you don't have any interaction between year and season in your model and you always predict for the same years. Calculate the predictions from the coefficients manually. That should make it more obvious why you must get the same standard deviation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Roland, it's much appreciated. I understand your point that the seasonal effect is the same for each year due to the absence of an interaction term, but what I'm struggling with is why for a particular year that the model prediction is an equal distance from all seasonal data points. 

My gut feeling was that because I don't have an interaction term between season and year -- and therefore the seasonal effect is the same for all years -- that this would mean that the model wouldn't pass exactly in between these points. (That is, the fit wouldn't be great.)